# Bot framework - PromptDialog.Choice has duplicate replies

Tags: c#, botframework

In Bot Framework, while using C#, I have a Dialog and use PromptDialog.Choice to let users select a question they are interested in.

But when it runs, I got duplicate replies, as seen in the following picture:

[image]

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    this.ShowOptions(context);
}

private void ShowOptions(IDialogContext context)
{
    PromptDialog.Choice(
        context,
        this.OnOptionSelected,
        new List() { ImageOption, ToolOption },
        "Please select one of the following category.",
        "Not a valid option",
        3);
}

private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable result)
{
    string optionSelected = await result;
    switch (optionSelected)
    {
        case ImageOption:
            context.Call(new ImgRelated(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
            break;

        case ToolOption:
            context.Call(new ToolPBmDailog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
            break;
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

`ShowOptions` needs to be an async method, and it needs to be called with `context.Wait(this.ShowOptions)` in `StartAsync` instead of just straight up calling it.

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    context.Wait(this.ShowOptions);
}

public async virtual Task ShowOptions(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;

    PromptDialog.Choice<string>(
        context,
        this.OnOptionSelected,
        new List() { ImageOption, ToolOption },
        "Please select one of the following category.",
        "Not a valid option",
        3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `OnOptionSelected` method so as it waits for an input from user before executing it. Also, make the `ShowOptions` method as async, otherwise you might get an exception, because right now, your `ShowOptions` method returns void to the `StartAsync` method. The `IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>` waits for a response from user.  Try the following and see if it works for you.

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await this.ShowOptions(context);
    }

    private async Task ShowOptions(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, 
                     new List() { ImageOption, ToolOption }, 
                     "Please select one of the following category.", 
                     "Not a valid option", 3);
    }

    private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        string optionSelected = await result;
        switch (optionSelected)
        {
            case ImageOption:
                context.Call(new ImgRelated(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                break;

            case ToolOption:
                context.Call(new ToolPBmDailog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                break;
        }
    }
```